# i am create method in java using selenium and i got an error

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("launching chrome browser");
    String driverPath = "D:/Chrome/";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath+"chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    ((LoadDvWeb) driver.navigate()).to("http://192.168.1.21");
}
```

I got below error in this code
Error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Test.LoadDvWeb.main(LoadDvWeb.java:14)

Comment: i use ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

Comment: but still same error occur

Comment: What does LoadDvWeb do?

Comment: LoadDvWeb is my Class name i am launch the browser and now its working but now i have retturn onr more code for test login page which is not been execute

Comment: It is pretty clear what it is. But what does it do? Why are you using to cast the driver?

Comment: i m generating automated testing on web browser.... if have to execute the test if login page its define in main class only

Comment: Update your question with LoadDvWeb.java

Answer (score 0):

You havn't initialized the variable **driver**.

Modify the line as:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it doesn't read the path of `chromedriver`. In Windows, please try to add escape chars, like this:

```
String driverPath = "D:\\Chrome\\";
```

This is how I normally do in my code.